# would I be making - what kind of grammatical structure is that?

Tags: usage

> How **would** I **be making** it his day by **buying** myself a new dress?

Tell me please what kind of grammatical structure is that?
Why -ing form is there?

Comment: Are you sure the original didn't say, "How would I be making his day...?" (i.e., no "it")

Comment: Sure.  The original didn't say, "How would I be making his day...?

Answer (score 1):

- How would I be making it his day **by buying myself a new dress**?

The idiom is: to make someone's day. **This can include it or not.**

- How would I be making his day by buying myself a new dress?

***To make someone's day***

**Question form**: **Are you making (it) my day** **by [doing whatever]?**.

**You are making my day by** [doing whatever].

You are making my day by **giving me a compliment.**

Giving me a compliment is **how** you are making my day.

So,

"**Buying myself a new dress** is **how** I am making his day".

**Question form in the conditional**:

- How would I be making his day by [buying myself a new dress].
- Would I be making his day if I bought myself a new dress?

How would x be [making etc.] is the conditional tense for this idiom, preceded by the question word HOW.

As in: How do you know that? How would you know that?

If I say: I'm going to make it your day. The it refers to the day. It would be the same as: I'm going to make this your day. It is not required but can be used.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me as a mix between "make it his business" and "make his day".

So really the discussion here is this, and not so much the "would I be making."

To "make one's day" is to make a person happy for the entire day although this can also be used sardonically as well ("The rain messing up my near hairstyle really *made my day*.")

To "make it one's business" is to interest oneself in a situation or to suggest that a situation is of certain importance to that person.